# How to Calculate progress value on some opreation in android

Tags: android

I am working on a task to read SD card files and I am showing a progress bar with calculated percentage based on SD card files like some antivirus software in Android.  I don't know how to implement this functionality.  My SD card read files code shown below:

```
File root = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
scan(root);
```

Scan function code shown below:

```
   public void scan (File path) {

            for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile()) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),f.getAbsoluteFile().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        }
```

Can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that a file list has a length. You can use this length in your loop to compute a percentage of number of files completed so far. Perhaps something like:

```
File[] files = path.listFiles();
for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    // Report i / files.length percent done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void scan (final File path) {

         float progress = 0.0f;
         int count  = 0;
         for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
             if (f.isFile()) {
                Toast.makeText(getFragmentContext(),f.getAbsoluteFile().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             else {

             }
             count++;
             progress += ( (float)count / (float)path.listFiles().length ) * 100;
         }
     }
```

Hope This is what you want.